# Is it possible to get terminal input in init()?

Tags: java, terminal, init

I have this code:

```
public class test {

    init() {
        //How can i get access of args?
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        new test();
}
```

How can I get access of "args" in `init()`?

Comment: Recommend reading up on [Java code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) - class names should be capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

Define an instance field within the class, and create constructor to accept the array and set the field:

```
   public class test{

       String[] args;

       public test(String[] args){
           this.args = args;
       }
       init(){

       }
   } 

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       new test(args);
   }
```

Or pass it as an argument to the method.

```
init(String[] args){

}
```

If `init` requires anything within the `test` class, you must create an instance of the class

```
test t = new test();
t.init(args);
```

If `init` does not require a new instance of test (eg doesn't access any instance variables or methods) you could define init as static and directly call the method:

```
static init(String[] args){//method declaration

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
   test.init(args);//call the method in a static way
}
```

Comment: init runs before the constructor for me :/ so i've tried this

Comment: `init` is currently defined as an instance method, so the constructor must be called prior. Does `init` depend upon anything within `test` - eg can you define `init` as static?

Comment: I can't make init static as it is now. Is there any way to pass directly a argument, when u create a object of "test", to init() ?

Comment: `Is there any way to pass directly a argument, when u create a object of "test", to init() ` Yes, as the first part of my answer suggests pass the array to the Constructor. If calling `init` from constructor then just pass the constructor parameters to init

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it as an argument.

```
public class test{

    init(String[] args){
     //How can i get access of args?
    } 

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        test t = new test();
        t.init(args);
    }
}
```

Remember, you should capitalise your class names.

Comment: The problem is that i need args in init(). When I write test t = new test(); starts the init and i dont have args at that moment